# grouping lines from a txt file using filters in Linux to create multiple txt files

Tags: linux, filter, grep

I have a txt file, where each line starts with participant No, followed by the date and other variables (numbers only), so has format:

```
 S001_2 20090926 14756 93    
 S002_2 20090803 15876 13
```

I want to write a script that creates smaller txt files containing only 20 participants per file (so first one will contain lines from S001_2 to S020_2;second from S021_2 to S040_2; total number of subjects approximately 200). However, subjects are not organized, therefore I can`t set a range with sed.

What would be the best command to filter ppts into chunks depending on what number (SOO1_2) the line starts with?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [split](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?split) command to split a file (or a filtered result) without ranges and sed. According to the documentation, this should work:

cat file.txt | split -l 20 - PREFIX

This will produce the files PREFIXaa, PREFIXab, ... (Note that it does not add the .txt extension to the file name!)

If you want to filter the files first, in the way @Sergey described:

cat file.txt | sort | split -l 20 - PREFIX

Answer (score 1):

Sort without any parameters should be suitable, because there are leading zeros in your numbers like `S001_2`. So, first sort the file:

```
sort file.txt > sorted.txt
```

Then you will be able to set ranges with sed for file_sort.txt

This looks like a whole script for splitting sorted file into 20-line files:

```sh
num=1;
i=1;
lines=`wc -l sorted.txt | cut -d' ' -f 1`;#get number of lines
while [ $i -lt $lines ];do
    sed -n $i,`echo $i+19 | bc`p sorted.txt > file$num;
    num=`echo $num+1 | bc`;
    i=`echo $i+20 | bc`;
done;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ split -d -l 20 file.txt -a3 db_
```

produces: db_000, db_001, db_002, ..., db_N